# How to unset "ENV" in dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

For some certain reasons, I have to set "http_proxy" and "https_proxy" `ENV` in my dockerfile. I would like to now unset them because there are also some building process can't be done through the proxy.

```
# dockerfile

# ... some process

ENV http_proxy=http://...
ENV https_proxy=http://...

# ... some process that needs the proxy to finish

UNSET ENV http_proxy # how to I unset the proxy ENV here?
UNSET ENV https_proxy

# ... some process that can't use the proxy
```

Comment: Is this just for specific host names? There's a `no_proxy` variable that may be more appropriate for your use case.

Comment: There's a no_proxy variable which can work but it is not standardized and you might get different result on different application. See: [link](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2021/01/27/we-need-to-talk-no-proxy/)

Answer (score 44):

It depends on what effect you are trying to achieve.

Note that, as a matter of pragmatics (i.e. how developers actually speak), "unsetting a variable" can mean two things: removing it from the environment, or setting the variable to an empty value. Technically, these are two different operations. In practice though I have not run into a case where the software I'm trying to control differentiates between the variable being absent from the environment, and the variable being present in the environment but set to an empty value. I generally can use either method to get the same result.

#### If you don't care whether the variable is in the layers produced by Docker, but leaving it with a non-empty value causes problems in later build steps.

For this case, you can use `ENV VAR_NAME=` at the point in your Dockerfile from which you want to unset the variable. Syntactic note: Docker allows two syntaxes for `ENV`: this `ENV VAR=1` is the same as `ENV VAR 1`. You can separate the variable name from the value with a space or an equal sign. When you want to "unset" a variable by setting it to an empty value you must use the equal sign syntax or you get an error at build time.

So for instance, you could do this:

```
ENV NOT_SENSITIVE some_value
RUN something

ENV NOT_SENSITIVE=
RUN something_else
```

When `something` runs, `NOT_SENSITIVE` is set to `some_value`. When `something_else` runs, `NOT_SENSITIVE` is set to the empty string.

It is important to note that doing `unset NOT_SENSITIVE` as a shell command will not **affect anything else than what executes in this shell.** Here's an example:

```
ENV NOT_SENSITIVE some_value
RUN unset NOT_SENSITIVE && printenv NOT_SENSITIVE || echo "does not exist"

RUN printenv NOT_SENSITIVE
```

The first `RUN` will print `does not exist` because `NOT_SENSITIVE` is unset when `printenv` executes and because it is unset `printenv` returns a non-zero exit code which causes the `echo` to execute. The second `RUN` is not affected by the `unset` in the first `RUN`. It will print `some_value` to the screen.

> But what if I need to **remove** the variable from the environment, not just set it to an empty value?

In this case using `ENV VAR_NAME=` won't work. I don't know of any way to tell Docker "from this point on, you must remove this variable from the environment, not just set it to an empty value".

If you still want to use `ENV` to set your variable, then you'll have to start each `RUN` in which you want the variable to be unset with `unset VAR_NAME`, which will unset it for *that* specific `RUN` only.

#### If you want to prevent the variable from being present in the layers produced by Docker.

Suppose that variable contains a secret and the layer could fall into the hands of people who should not have the secret. In this case you **CANNOT** use `ENV` to set the variable. A variable set with `ENV` is baked into the layers to which it applies and cannot be removed from those layers. In particular, (assuming the variable is named `SENSITIVE`) running

```
RUN unset SENSITIVE
```

**does not do *anything* to remove it from the layer.** The `unset` command above only removes `SENSITIVE` from the shell process that `RUN` starts. It affects only that shell. It won't affect shells spawned by `CMD`, `ENTRYPOINT`, or any command provided through running `docker run` at the command line.

In order to prevent the layers from containing the secret, I would use `docker build --secret=` and `RUN --mount=type=secret...`. For instance, assuming that I've stored my secret in a file named `sensitive`, I could have a `RUN` like this:

```
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=sensitive,target=/root/sensitive \
 export SENSITIVE=$(cat /root/sensitive) \
 && [[... do stuff that requires SENSITIVE ]] \
```

*Note that the command given to `RUN` does not need to end with `unset SENSITIVE`.* Due to the way processes and their environments are managed, setting `SENSITIVE` in the shell spawned by `RUN` does not have any effect beyond what that shell itself spawns. Environment changes in this shell won't affect future shells nor will it affect what Docker bakes into the layers it creates.

Then the build can be run with:

```
$ DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --secret id=secret,src=path/to/sensitive [...]
```

The environment for the `docker build` command needs `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1` to use BuildKit because this method of passing secrets is only available if Docker uses BuildKit to build the images.

Answer (score 14):

If one needs env vars during the image build but they should not persist, just clear them. In the following example, the running container shows empty env vars.

Dockerfile

```
# set proxy
ARG http_proxy
ARG https_proxy
ARG no_proxy
ENV http_proxy=$http_proxy
ENV https_proxy=$http_proxy
ENV no_proxy=$no_proxy

# ... do stuff that needs the proxy during the build, like apt-get, curl, et al.

# unset proxy
ENV http_proxy=
ENV https_proxy=
ENV no_proxy=
```

build.sh

```
docker build -t the-image \
    --build-arg http_proxy="$http_proxy" \
    --build-arg https_proxy="$http_proxy" \
    --build-arg no_proxy="$no_proxy" \
    --no-cache \
    .
```

run.sh

```
docker run --rm -i \
    the-image \
    sh << COMMANDS
        env
COMMANDS
```

Output

```
no_proxy=
https_proxy=
http_proxy=
...
```

Comment: will this expose the env in the intermediate layers?

Comment: This does not work (tested on debian 9). no_proxy is a value which is set by the docker settings in ~/.docker/config.json. This is the value which will land in the image, even if you write "ENV no_proxy=".

Comment: This also does not work in case with node.js processes -- node.js seems to be really unhappy with empty http[s]_proxy env vars :(

Comment: We don't really need the ENV lines.  We can simply use `ARG http_proxy="http://host.docker.internal:3128/"` or whatever your proxy is.

Comment: Don't we need the ENV lines if we pass in the build args in order to remove them from within the container by overriding them? Hardcoded build args are stored in history, no?

Answer (score 13):

According to docker docs you need to use shell command instead:

```
FROM alpine
RUN export ADMIN_USER="mark" \
&& echo $ADMIN_USER > ./mark \
&& unset ADMIN_USER
CMD sh
```

See https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#env for more details.

Comment: > Each ENV line creates a new intermediate layer, just like RUN commands. This means that *even if you unset the environment variable in a future layer*, it still persists in this layer and its value can be dumped. You can test this by creating a Dockerfile like the following, and then building it.

Answer (score 9):

**Short-answer**:

Try to avoid unnecessary environment variables, so you don't need to unset them.

In case you have to unset for a command you can do the following:

```
RUN unset http_proxy https_proxy no_proxy \
    && execute_your_command_here
```

In case you have to unset for the built image you can do the following:

```
FROM ubuntu_with_http_proxy

ENV http_proxy= \
    https_proxy= \
    no_proxy=
```

Once environment variables are set using the `ENV` instruction we can't really unset them as it is detailed:

> Each ENV line creates a new intermediate layer, just like RUN commands. This means that even if you unset the environment variable in a future layer, it still persists in this layer and its value can be dumped.

See: [Best practices for writing Dockerfiles](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#env)

**Details**:

I prefer to define `http_proxy` as an argument during build like the following:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ARG http_proxy=http://host.docker.internal:3128 
ARG https_proxy=http://host.docker.internal:3128 
ARG no_proxy=.your.domain,localhost,127.0.0.1,.docker.internal
```

On corporate proxy we need authentication anyways, so we need to configure local proxy server listening on `127.0.0.1:3128` witch is accessible over `host.docker.internal:3128` from containers. This way it also works on docker desktop if we connect to corporate network over VPN (with local/home network blocked).

Setting `no_proxy` is also important to avoid flooding the proxy server.

See the following article for more details on no_proxy related topics:

- [Can we standardize NO_PROXY?](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2021/01/27/we-need-to-talk-no-proxy/)

Sometimes it is also good to read the related documentation:

- [ENV](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env)
- [ARG](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg)

In case we need to configure those environment variables we can use the following command:

- during build ([link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg)):

```
docker build ... --build-arg http_proxy='http://alternative.proxy:3128/' ...
```

- during runs ([link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file)):

```
docker run ... -env http_proxy='http://alternative.proxy:3128/' ...
```

Also note that we don't even need to define proxy related arguments since those are already predefine according to the following section:

[Dockerfile reference - Predefined ARGs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#predefined-args)

Answer (score 0):

You can add below lines in the Dockerfile

```
ENV http_proxy ""
ENV https_proxy ""
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the secret approach didn't work because I needed the env variable to persist in the container when I ran it in interactive mode but then needed to completely remove the variable for a later stage build for production.

What worked was in building for the development phase I appended the environment variable to the /root/.basrc file as

```
RUN echo export AWS_PROFILE=role-name >> /root/.bashrc
``

In the production stage of the build I then removed the last line of /root/.bashrc:
```

RUN sed -i '$ d'  /root/.bashrc

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an example  as a note of programmatically deleting variables.
It shows how to unset variables at each assembly level and through the entry point.

This is indicated as an example if there is a direct need to remove variables.

```
FROM busybox:latest

ENV HELLO=hello

RUN touch /unset_env.sh && chmod 775 /unset_env.sh ; touch /entrypoint.sh && chmod 775 /entrypoint.sh

#example - unset variables in entrypoint
RUN <<EOF
cat <<EOF2 >/entrypoint.sh
#!/bin/sh
source /unset_env.sh
cat /run_env.txt
sh
EOF2
EOF

#adding instructions
RUN echo "unset HELLO">>/unset_env.sh

#example - unset variables in installation layer
RUN source /unset_env.sh; \
echo "$(set)">/run_env.txt

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
# ENTRYPOINT ["sh","-c","source /unset_env.sh;sh"]
```

`docker build -t test . &&  docker run --rm --name test -it test`