# How to use NULL in environment variables supplied to docker run?

Tags: ruby, docker, environment-variables

I am supplying environment variables in docker run as `docker run --env-file <env_file_path>....`. The Dockerfile executes a ruby script which reads the env variables.

```
# environment variable file
TEST_1=NULL
TEST_2=
TEST_3=""
```

```rb
# ruby script
print ENV['TEST_1'] # "NULL"
print ENV['TEST_2'] # ""
print ENV['TEST_3'] # "\"\""
```

How can I receive a `nil` values in ruby from the environment variables? What should the supplied environment variable value be?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I receive a nil values in ruby from the environment variables? What should the supplied value be?

You can't, not directly.  Unlike a language like ruby, environment variables do not have a concept of null values.

You'll have to check for and convert a chosen value like an empty string, `NULL` or `nil` to an actual `nil` in your code.

You could use the mere presence / absence of the env variable, but the issue with that is that [you can't *unset* an environment variable once it's set with docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55789409/how-to-unset-env-in-dockerfile),  only set it to empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be nil?  Can you use undefined instead?

If you're doing an if check in the code: `if env.test_1` then you could just not define it in the file.

Comment: True, I could do that, I was just curious if there was a better way.

Answer (score 1):

The value of an environment variable (in terms of the operating system) is a string, and you can't beat this, in particular not with a language which has a very unusualy idea of a *null pointer* (since nil is an object of a full-featured class in Ruby, much different to i.e. C or Java).

Usually (when seen from i.e. shell programming), we sometimes distinguish between an environment variable which is **empty**, and one which is **undefined**. This you can do in your Ruby too:

```
ENV.has_key?('V') # -> true if defined, false if undefined
ENV['V'] # -> trueish if defined, nil if undefined
```

If you know that an environment variable is defined, you can check whether it is empty, by

```
ENV['V'].empty?
```

Transfering the Ruby type system to a data model established by the whole operating system, is usually futile, however there **is** a way, if you can live with restrictions:

Assuming that you need the environment variables to transport Ruby data (`nil`, arrays of strings, or whatever) from one Ruby process to another Ruby process, you can of course **serialize** the data. Serialization means that you create a string representation of the data (which makes it suitable for being stored in an environment variable) and deserialize it in the receiveing process.

Ruby comes with 3 serialization methods: `JSON`, `YAML` and (the most general and flexible one) `Marshal`. With JSON and YAML, you have even a chance to deserialize in a different language. With Marshal, you have to use the same Ruby implementation on the sending and receiving end.

With all serialization methods, you indeed can represent a Ruby `nil` in an Environment variable, for instance:

```
ENV['V']=Marshal.dump(nil) # serializing

v=Marshal.load(ENV['V']) # deserializing
```